# Tesseract on Mac OS X: Finding libcairo.so and libtesseract.so for use with text2image

Tags: macos, ocr, tesseract, text2image

Anyone running Tesseract on Mac? I am trying to use the text2image tool from the /training directory. But it fails with the following errors:

```
./text2image: line 202: cd: /usr/local/google/home/rays/src/opensrc/tesseract-ocr/training: No such file or directory
clang: error: no such file or directory: '../api/.libs/libtesseract.so'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so'
```

The first one is particularly strange. As if a developer had hard-coded his local working directory. However, the line number doesn't match up with the source and the name "rays" is not found anywhere.

So, for the next two errors: I have installed Tesseract from source as per the intructions. It works fine. Then, I had a hard time getting text2image running, due to a whole bunch of missing libraries. In the end, I worked it out using Fink as package manager and a build script found here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/roxlu/1322204eabbd5d42c2d0/raw/1b8546cfaef56b2bc5b120a8b201e6ddaf5bcad6/build_unix_dependencies.sh

But the two libraries mentioned in the subject line are still missing: libcairo.so and libtesseract.so. I do have the following on my system: 
- libtesseract.3.dylib
- libtesseract.a
- libtesseract.la
- libcairo.2.dylib

I am not sure, if the .dylib's can somehow be made in shared object files (.so). 
Any ideas?

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: `dylib` is OSX equivalent of Linux `so` or Windows `dll`. Seems that you already built everything. So try creating a couple symbolic links and see if that moves.

Comment: Do you mean a link from libtesseract.dylib to libtesseract.so?

Comment: ok, it worked. I created two symlinks in the respective directories like so: sudo ln -s /opt/X11/lib/libcairo.2.dylib  ./libcairo.so AND  sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/libtesseract.3.dylib ./libtesseract.so. (I am getting a different error now - of course; missing lpango library...)